# Mongoose Put using req.body. Populate some fields or empty string others

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I’m copying the req.body value to an object literal to populate foods in my mongo table. However, some foods might not come in the req.body so I’m wondering if there’s a way to use an OR statement.

Eg

```
color: req.body.color || ‘’
```

I need to try and build an object to run a findByIdAndUpdate(id, newObj, {new: true})

This keeps failing and I’m not understanding why.

Comment: is there any error ? can you share the detailed code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operators.

Example:

```
var someObj = {
   color: req.body.color ? req.body.color : ''
}
```